# Using both startUpdatingLocation and startMonitoringSignificantChanges?

Tags: iphone, ios, cllocationmanager

Is it advisable or any issues with calling both startUpdatingLocation and startMonitoringSignificantChanges vs. one or the other? I understand the benefits of the significant changes call re: battery life, but when using it am seeing inconsistency with it firing the didUpdateToLocation, sometimes doesn't fire at all even though I know I've setup locations where I know it should fire when I'm at the location but doesn't. I'm able to verify my results for my app vs. another app that does very similar behavior, including both mine and the other app running in the background (UIBackgroundModes does have the 'App registers for location updates' setting in the plist). If I try using just the significant changes, the results are not consistent. If I use both, I get accurate results + the added benefit (need) for getting notified if/when the app is terminated. I want to not kill the battery life by using the startUpdatingLocation, and have tried calling the stopUpdatingLocation and then subsequently calling the startMonitoringSignificantChanges in the applicationDidEnterBackground in order to help conserve battery life while in the background, but can't seem to understand why relying on the significant changes is not working consistently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple suggests that you use `-startUpdatingLocation` while your app is in the foreground, and `-startMonitoringSignificantChanges` while in the background. Using both while the app is in the foreground is likely just a waste and more likely to be more work to handle the events than just monitoring `-didUpdateToLocation`. Upon backgrounding, you can switch off the GPS mode and switch to something more low powered. You have to assume that the user won't care as much for accuracy once you've been backgrounded or closed.